# Not showing reCAPTCHA icon on ios in react-native app

Tags: react-native-ios, invisible-recaptcha

I am using `react-native-recaptcha-v3`, when I tested it on android devices it showing recaptcha icon and working fine. but in ios devices are not showing the icon and getting the warning message: 
"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Unable to open URL: about:blank. Add about to LSApplicationQuriesSchemes in your info.plist"

I am tryed this also "originWhitelist={['*']}" in webview but nothin changes.

please help me to show the reCAPTCHA icon in ios devices as showing in android.

Aditionaals Info:-
    react: 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.60.5
    react-native-recaptcha-v3: 0.0.16
    Node: 8.15.0
    npm: 6.4.1

Comment: What did you want to ask?

Comment: how can i show the reCAPTCHA icon and rid from warning

Comment: Plz update your question for more detail.